# How do you commit a front-end and back-end project that are in one single parent folder?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to find the a good solution for committing both the front and back-end projects onto one GitHub repository.

I came across BradTraversy's sample project and I want to emulate this style onto my own repository.

https://github.com/bradtraversy/react_express_starter

How does he have both the front and back-end projects inside each other? When I try to imitate this, I get an error saying I am adding an embedded repo and it hints at submodules (which I've read is not ideal for beginners since it complicates things down the line)

sample error from google:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/embedded-git-repository-warning/

I see that Brad's repo is utilizing some sort of tree/master/ in his url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Brad isn't using any `git submodule`. He's using a plain git repo which happen to have `server.js` and the `client` in the same directory and he uses `npm` to run them. You can also do this.

In a new directory, install `express` and write your `server.js`

```
git init# a new git repo.
npm init #creates a package.json
npm install express #this will create /node_modules and package-lock.json
vim server.js #write a express server app
```

Now create a new react app

```
create-react-app client #this will create a /client folder which will be react client
```

Modify `package.json` so you can run `npm run dev`

```
{
"name": "temp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "server.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
}
}
```

Comment: I still get the same warnings when I try to push this project format onto github

Comment: @ChrisC. You only need to track the root of the folder. So only `git init` once. If you have a `git tracked` directory inside a git tracked we are dealing with `git modules`. So you should remove your directory's (/server and /client) git tracking

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for your help!